# Convert string to object array javascript

Tags: javascript, strings, array

I want to convert string to object array. Suppose I have following string.

```
const str = "someValue,display";
```

I want to convert it like following.

```
[{
  columnVal: "someValue",
  display: true
}]
```

if it's display then I want value as true if noDisplay then false.

I tried following but, to me it doesn't seems like best solution.

```js
const val = "someValue,display";
const obj = {};

val.split(",").forEach((str, index) => {
    if(index === 0) {
        obj.columnVal = str;
  } else {
    if(str == "display") {
        obj.display = true;
    } else {
        obj.display = false;
    }
  }
})
console.log([obj]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified by using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into an array, followed by simple assignment into the object `obj`. While it may not be much more efficient it can eliminate the need to use the `forEach` method.

```js
const val = "someValue,display";
const [columnVal, displayValue] = val.split(",");
const obj = {columnVal, display: displayValue === "display"};

console.log([obj]);
```

The variable name `obj` isn't very descriptive but there isn't much context about how it is used.

A good habit and recommendation of many style guides is to use strict equality operators (i.e. `===`, `!==`) whenever possible (like is used in the snippet above). The problem with loose comparisons is that it has [so many weird rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494) one would need to memorize in order to be confident in its proper usage.